# HTML Validation Issue

Tags: html

Line 101, Column 86: document type does not allow element "input" here; missing one of "th", "td" start-tag

Here is the code:

```
<input type="submit" name = "b1" value = "Calculate" onclick = "calculate()"/>

<form name="frm1" action="">
                <fieldset>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Weight:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="number1"/></td>
                            <td>Distance:</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="number2"/></td>
                            <td>Answer =</td>
                            <td><input type="text" name="number3"/></td>
                            <input type="submit" name = "b1" value = "Calculate" onclick = "calculate()"/>
                        </tr>
                    </table>    
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Here is the function:

```
<script type="">
        function calculate()
        {
            A = document.frm1.number1.value;
            B = document.frm1.number2.value;
            C = (A*B*1.036);
            document.frm1.number3.value = C
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Where is "th", "td" ?

Comment: Well, you at least have to provide more context. Could you post a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you are trying to put an input element as a child element of a table row.

That isn't allowed and does not make sense.

Either place it outside the table or inside a table cell.

Answer (score 2):

It should look like this

```
  <form name="frm1" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Weight:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="number1"/></td>
                    <td>Distance:</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="number2"/></td>
                    <td>Answer =</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="number3"/></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name = "b1" value = "Calculate" onclick = "calculate()"/></td>
                </tr>
            </table>    
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```